# Angular 5 application CSS fix position of one div, while second one is scrollable

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having an issue with CSS on my angular application. 
Here a picture of my structure for now : 
[image]

I am trying to disable scrolling in `Div1` and have `Div2` still scrollable.

Here's my css for now :

```
.div0 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div2 {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

But it seems to do nothing, I still have the full scrolling on the app. I tried to put `overflow: hidden;` in body (index.html), but then it disables the scroll completly. Any ideas?

Sorry if I did a noob mistake, I'm a complete beginner in CSS.

Comment: try putting a max-height on .div2 and an overflow-y of scroll.  Not tested, but I think it should work.

Comment: Try using `overflow-y: hidden` for `div1` and `overflow-y: scroll` for `div2`. Checkout the [CSS Overflow-y property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`.div2 {height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}`

Answer (score -1):

please try below styles.

```
.div0 {
     position: relative;
}

.div1, .div2 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```